# Only last text block out put in Animation Nodes loop

Tags: animation-nodes, instances, looping

I have an Animation Nodes loop that takes three text blocks and three text objects and outputs them. The debug is showing the individual texts are intact, but only the last text block is output. What am I doing wrong?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment all three text objects use the **same underlaying data block**. So when you change one, you are changing all.

There are two main ways to fix it:

1. Enable **Deep Copy** in the Object Instancer node.
2. Turn off **Copy from Source** and switch the created object type to "Text".